# Extracting a matrix from a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array

I have a three-dimensional array and a vector

```
A = array(1:24, dim = 2:4 )
v = c(3,2,1,2)
```

I would like to produce a two-dimensional matrix, where we pick only one column from each 3rd dimension "block" `i` -- the one indexed by `v[i]`. For instance, the first column of the output matrix should be the third column of `A[,,1]`, because `v[1] = 3`.

Comment: Is `res<-matrix(ncol=length(v),nrow=dim(A)[1])` followed by `for (i in 1:length(v)) res[,i]<-A[,v[i],i]` your desired output?

Comment: do the below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plyr` to the rescue to transform array to a list of matrix. Then you can proceed to column extraction through `Map`:

```
library(plyr)

do.call(cbind, Map(function(m,i) m[,i], alply(A, 3), v))
#     1  2  3  4
#[1,] 5  9 13 21
#[2,] 6 10 14 22
```